# Does StyleCop.Analyzers support C# records?

Tags: c#, record, stylecop

**Problem description:**

When adding a `C#` record in a project with `StyleCop.Analyzers`, it shows the warning:

```
Warning AD0001  Analyzer 'StyleCop.Analyzers.DocumentationRules.SA1649FileNameMustMatchTypeName' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' with message 'Unhandled declaration kind: RecordDeclaration'.    

System.ArgumentException: Unhandled declaration kind: RecordDeclaration
       at StyleCop.Analyzers.Helpers.NamedTypeHelpers.GetNameOrIdentifier(MemberDeclarationSyntax member)
       at StyleCop.Analyzers.Helpers.FileNameHelpers.GetConventionalFileName(MemberDeclarationSyntax declaration, FileNamingConvention convention)
       at StyleCop.Analyzers.DocumentationRules.SA1649FileNameMustMatchTypeName.Analyzer.HandleSyntaxTree(SyntaxTreeAnalysisContext context, StyleCopSettings settings)
       at StyleCop.Analyzers.AnalyzerExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<RegisterSyntaxTreeAction>b__0(SyntaxTreeAnalysisContext c)
       at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.AnalyzerExecutor.<>c.<ExecuteSyntaxTreeActionsCore>b__59_1(ValueTuple`2 data)
       at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.AnalyzerExecutor.ExecuteAndCatchIfThrows_NoLock[TArg](DiagnosticAnalyzer analyzer, Action`1 analyze, TArg argument, Nullable`1 info)
```

Is it a bug in `StyleCop.Analyzers`?

**Steps to reproduce:**

- Create a new `.Net6` console project (or even `.Net5`).
- Add a `C#` record in it: `public record Member(string FirstName, string LastName);`
- Install the package `StyleCop.Analyzers v1.1.118`
- Look in the Visual Studio Error List, and you will see the warning.

Comment: https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/pull/3215 - odd that it still happens in the latest beta, maybe you should raise an issue with them

Comment: Were you able to find a workaround without having to use the beta version?

Comment: No I couldn't find any workaround. I upgraded to the beta version, and so far it's ok

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you @stuartd you pointed me to the right direction.

It is indeed a bug in Stylecop 1.1.X

It was corrected in the [StyleCop.Analyzers.Unstable v1.2.0-beta.161](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/issues/3213#issuecomment-725780613). but unfortunately, it is not included in the stable version yet. So the workaround I see for now is to use the unstable version